# How do I modify properties of siblings with CSS selectors like :focus?

Tags: css, forms, events, focus, css-selectors

I am having trouble with some code on my site, http://ethoma.com/wp/. In the search bar, on the left side, I want the usually dark gray "hit enter to search" to turn a light gray when the search field (its sibling) :focus is triggered. Here is the code I currently have:

```
    #s
{
    min-width:98%;
    background-color:#2a2a2a;
    color:#d3d3d3;
    border:2px solid #000000;
    font-size:.85 em;
    height:1.9em;
    display:inline !important;
    border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#s:focus
{
    border:2px solid #2a2a2a;
}

#searchsub
{
    color:#2a2a2a;
    text-align:right;
    font-size:.65em;
    font-weight:lighter;
}

#s:focus #searchsub
{
    color:#cccccc;
}
```

Okay, #s is the search field and #searchsub is the div that I want to turn #cccccc (light gray). The last set of curly braces seems to be where I am having the problem (not the braces themselves, but the selector above it). As I said #s is a sibling of #searchsub and vice versa.

Comment: Have you thought about using jQuery to do this?

Comment: You should paste the relevant markup from your theme to save us the effort of having to follow a link in order to search for the relevant markup.

Comment: More recently CSS has introduced :focus-within which will be set on a parent if any of its descendants gains focus. Thus we don't have to worry quite so much about direct siblings etc.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Like stefmikhail said, the space in your selector means `#searchsub` is *inside* `#s`. As far as HTML is concerned, though, that is obviously wrong because `input` fields are empty elements and you can't have other elements inside them.

You want to use the adjacent sibling selector `+` instead, since `#searchsub` is the sibling that comes after `#s`:

```
#s:focus + #searchsub
{
    color:#cccccc;
}
```

Comment: Should be mentioned however that the adjacent selector is part of CSS3, and as much as I wish this wasn't the case, CSS3 is *not* fully supported as of yet. If you're wanting users of Internet Explorer 7 and below to have this functionality, it might be buggy (in the case of IE7) or non-existent (in the case of IE6 and below). I wish we didn't have to code for such browsers, but my philosophy is when it concerns a hover state, use something that will work for all, not just for most. But hey, it's your call. I think CSS3 selectors are way cool!

Comment: @stefmikhail: You mistook the CSS2 adjacent sibling selector `+` for the CSS3 general sibling selector `~`. Both are very well supported in IE7+.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
+
```

**adjacent sibling combinator** 
(only if it immediately follows the first element)

```
~
```

**general sibling combinator**
(only if it follows the first element (though not necessarily immediately)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that by placing `#searchsub` after `#s:focus` in `#s:focus #searchsub`, you're telling CSS to act upon the id `#searchsub` *inside* the id `#s`.

I agree with JamWaffles that you could do this with javascript. I would do it with jQuery, and if you would like, I can post how.

Comment: @Rikudo Sennin I never said it wasn't doable with CSS, I only said I would choose to use javascript for this, seeing as using CSS for this will not work in older IE browsers.

Comment: When something is doable with css alone. It is usually best to do so. The top I would go to if absolutely needed, I'd use Modernizr to check if possible and use JavaScript else.