# Display element if sibling has focus

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a table in a Vue template for viewing and saving account data. I want to show a save button element next to each field when it has focus. I can achieve this in the following way:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      accountitems5: 'some value for 5',
      accountitems6: 'value for six',
      sbutton5: false,
      sbutton6: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    saveData (inputval) {
      // save function runs here
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<table class="accounttable" ref="my_tableinfo">
<tr><td class="values">
<input type="text" v-model="accountitems5" @blur="saveData(accountitems5),sbutton5 = false" @focus="sbutton5 = true"/><button v-if="sbutton5">save</button>
</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td class="values">
<input type="text" v-model="accountitems6" @blur="saveData(accountitems6),sbutton6 = false" @focus="sbutton6 = true"/><button v-if="sbutton6">save</button>
</td><td></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

But I was wondering if there is an easier and simpler way, just by referencing the sibling and checking for focus, instead of having to give each save button a unique value? I have tried various forms of `hasFocus()` but can't get any of them to work.

NOTE: I am looking for a solution that would involve less coding. A solution that necessitates more code that I have above would not really be a better one in this situation, for example.

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @billy, I was able to get it to work with css using `:focus-within` pseudo selector. But then I realized that this was supported in far too few browsers at the moment, so I need another solution or I fall back to unique values for each.

Comment: can you make a live demo of this ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. why? The above code works fine, I am just asking if there is another, simpler way to go about this, by identifying when the sibling has focus.

Comment: It would be easy to give you solution with your sample data

Comment: oh ok, I will make one.

Comment: There you go....

Comment: You should update your question to be up front about all your constraints and solutions that will not work for you.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way, and that you deleted your answer, which I thought could be very helpful for someone in a slightly different situation. Also, I think I was pretty upfront about looking for a SIMPLER way to accomplish what I want. To be perfectly honest, your component is more complicated than my exiting solution above.

Comment: But I added a note to make it crystal clear what type of solution I am looking for, I hope it meets with your approval.

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with Vue but could you potentially do this with CSS.

See
[How do I modify properties of siblings with CSS selecters like :focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224751/how-do-i-modify-properties-of-siblings-with-css-selecters-like-focus)

Comment: Thanks this is a great idea in theory, but my inputs are actually components that wrap the input and button elements, so I don't think it will work. (because adjacent sibling must immediately follow. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors.)

Comment: WAIT. I take it back. I was able to use css after all, but using the pseudo class `:focus-within`! thanks!

Comment: UGH, sorry, I take it back again. While this is technically possible, it isn't widely supported enough for me to be able to use it. :(